# Android Fragment Crashes after Firebase Firestore update field

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a field with an arrayList and it causes the fragment to crash without any error in the log. What I'm trying to do is:

```
DbShopItemT dbShopItem =new DbShopItemT();
                    dbShopItem.setName(item.getName());
                    dbShopItem.setPosition(item.getPosition());
                    dbShopItem.setType(item.getType());
                    dbShopItem.setPrice(item.getPrice());

                    tmpShopList=user.getShopList();
                    Log.e("tmpShopList",""+tmpShopList);
                    tmpShopList.add(dbShopItem);
                    userRef.document(userID).update("shopList",tmpShopList);
```

DbShopItemT looks like this:

```
    public DbShopItemT(int position, String name , String type , int price) {
    this.position = position;
    Name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.price=price;

}
```

The update happens , I can see the added item in the console but it crashes the fragment everytime. I've commented the update line only and no crashes are happening.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: there is nothing on the logcat errors

Answer (score 1):

It was all happening because I had a SnapShotListener on user and it was restarting over and over again. My bad